# OIDC ID Token nonce as "poor mans digital signature"

Tags: digital-signature, openid-connect

In absence of better solutions, is the `nonce` is an OpenID Connect ID Token usable to serve as digital signature. The process would be as follows:

1. A hash is created from the to-be-signed document/transaction.
2. This hash is then used as the `nonce` in the token request.
3. The resulting ID token is retained as digital signature of the document/transaction.
4. To verify the signature, we would check if 1) the ID token is issued and signed by a trusted party and 2) verify that its `nonce` matches the hash of the document/transaction.

Alternatively, if the authorization allows specifying the `aud` (through resource indicators) claim, the document/transaction URI could be set there, but the principle is the same.

Comment: *"In absence of better solutions"* - why should better solutions be absent in the first place? What stops you from using proper signatures and requires you to bend the OIDC protocol so that the meaning of the nonce gets changed?

Comment: *Alternatively, if the authorization allows specifying the aud (through resource indicators) claim, the document/transaction URI could be set there, but the principle is the same.*

Answer (score 4):

1. Signature is something that can only be created by the signer. Nobody else should be able to create the same signature. Where as in your approach hash can be created by anyone. Thus it will not confirm anything and thus it is not a signature.
2. Identical documents/transactions will produce identical hashes, means identical nonces. But every nonce should only be used once. Server should reject request if the same nonce is used more than once.

I think it is an XY problem. Explain, what your real problem is. It can have much better solutions.

Comment: In our case these assumptions are incorrect (the hash can not be created by anyone and each document/transaction is guaranteed to produce a unique hash). The problem at hand is that each transaction needs to be non-repudiably linked to a person. We have an external OIDC identity provider and integrating other external services is not an option at the moment.

Comment: Anyone can send a request to your server, e.g. using curl, Postman or similar tools. In particular, anyone can calculate hash and set it. It would be impossible, if you would sign it. If you sign it, then please add this after step 3 and before the current step 4.

Comment: Signatures are done *knowingly* and *willingly*. The fact that there is some hash does not prove any relation to any person. If case of normal PKI signature it is clear that user really *obtained* the content of the signed document, and user *knew* what user was going to sign, and user *wanted* to sign it. Whereas in your case none of these is true. If you mean that there is some transaction logged, then the prove is what it is - it is just a log. The hash in your approach has exactly as much proving power as an entry in the log. If you have logs, these hashes don't prove anything more.

Comment: Another problem. Since you don't use nonce as such, your application is open to replay attacks. If some request gives user some benefit, e.g. transfers 1000 USD to users account, a malicious user will send the same request to the application again and again...

Comment: ... If you implement additional business logic to prevent replay attacks on the business logic level, each such request will be expensive, because business logic consumes much resources (CPU, memory, network traffic) compared to check if the nonce was used. That's why multiple repeated requests from a malicious user can lead to another attack, resource exhaustion attack. Normal application would reject such requests immediately, *without triggering expensive business logic*, because nonce was already used. But you don't want to use nonce for the purpose it is usually used for.